# Editor with dictionary word completion

Tags: vim, emacs, autocomplete, gedit

Is there an linux editor which can autocomplete words from a dictionary?

I don't ask for autocompletion of already written words in a document (like gedit does). Also I am not looking for (personally overkilling editors) like vim or emacs. Mostly I write on texts and those editors are primarily focused on editing source code, which I do not (besides of writing some latex stuff).

I bet there are lots of people, who see vim or emacs as an overkill, and they would love to have such a feature, because it makes typing amazingly faster than without dictionary word completion.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't see why you find Vim as an overkill, but it *should* be able to do word completion based on dictionary, either [normally](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions), or [with plugins](https://github.com/reedes/vim-lexical). (I use Vim plugins only for programming syntax completion, so I haven't tested it, but if you decide to go with plugin, I recommend using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)).

The fact that these editors are primarily used for programming doesn't mean they can be used *only* for programming - they are still word editors and not IDEs.

I also found [this Q&A](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/is-there-any-text-editor-with-autocomplete) which is probably what you want. It describes the possibilities of word completion in Emacs and Sublime Text. I don't know which Linux distribution you use, however Sublime text 3 is currently available only as a .deb package (Sublime Text 2 should be available for all distros). If you don't want to use Vim or Emacs, Sublime Text with [this package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DictionaryAutoComplete) should be what are you looking for.